# Can't run LDA on Dataset[(scala.Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)] in Spark 2.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/v/23bttDZbE2A?rel=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&start=0) tutorial video on LDA example and I'm getting the following issue :

```
<console>:37: error: overloaded method value run with alternatives:
  (documents: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD[java.lang.Long,org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector])org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDAModel <and>
  (documents: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(scala.Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)])org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDAModel
  cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(scala.Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)])
     val model = run(lda_countVector)
                                   ^
```

So I want to convert this DF to RDD but it is always assigned as DataSet for me. Can anyone please look into this issue?

```
// Convert DF to RDD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
val lda_countVector = countVectors.map { case Row(id: Long, countVector: Vector) => (id, countVector) }
// import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
// lda_countVector: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)] = [_1: bigint, _2: vector]
```

Comment: can you give us the type of countVectors ?

Comment: countVectors.printSchema
​
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)</p>
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)

Comment: this is not the type but the schema.

Comment: Oh that is a dataframe - countVectors: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, features: vector]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark API changed between 1.x and 2.x branch. In particular `DataFrame.map` returns `Dataset` not an `RDD` so the result is not compatible with old MLlib `RDD`-based API. You should convert data to `RDD` first as followed :

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{DistributedLDAModel, LDA}

val a = Vectors.dense(Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
val b = Vectors.dense(Array(3.0, 4.0, 5.0))
val df = Seq((1L ,a), (2L, b), (2L, a)).toDF

val ldaDF = df.rdd.map { 
  case Row(id: Long, countVector: Vector) => (id, countVector) 
} 

val model = new LDA().setK(3).run(ldaDF)
```

or you can convert to typed dataset and then to RDD:

```
val model = new LDA().setK(3).run(df.as[(Long, Vector)].rdd)
```

Comment: Thanks eliasah for taking a look into this, appreciate it! I tried to implement this suggestion, now it gives me another exception https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8NpxtKK8m-8QzF5Ymg0aXRqRXc .However when I execute your code it works fine, so I will vote up and mark your suggestion as answer. If I figure out the issue in my data, I will respond to this thread.

Comment: That seems to be a Scala version error. Check if the cluster is running the same version of Scala you are.

Comment: Cluster is in Spark 2.0 Scala 2.10

Comment: Hi @eliasah is there a way to convert CountVectorizer to dense vector. I believe that LDA is throwing exception because CountVectorizer is givign sparse vector. That is why it seems to be working fine with your example but with mine it is not.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it in a new thread with its full description and error messages.

Comment: Wow this helped me! Thx so much for the SSCE !

Comment: You're welcome @javadba ! If I may ask, what is "SSCE" ? I'm not familiar with that acronym and I can't find it on the net.